# How to create a Parameter/Slot in a Storybook 7 AutoDoc Template Element populated by Story

Tags: typescript, storybook

I am creating a storybook for custom web components and I am not very familiar with React.

I have learned that you can create your own AutoDocs template using a `*.mdx` file according to the [storybook docs](https://storybook.js.org/docs/web-components/writing-docs/autodocs#with-mdx).

What I would like is to have my `*.stories.ts` to be able to use an AutoDocs template that has a `<Markdown></Markdown>` component that takes a parameter (a file name or import) and then renders it in the story as each of our components also have a `readme.md` file.

I already have a custom `*.mdx` template that I am using for the docs in my `.storybook/preview.ts` in the preview like so:

```
import type { Preview } from "@storybook/web-components";
import DocumentationTemplate from './DocumentationTemplate.mdx';

const preview: Preview = { 
  parameters: { 
    docs: { 
      page: DocumentationTemplate, 
    },
  }, 
};

export default preview;
```

The part I am unsure about is how to have a slot/parameter in my `DocumentationTemplate.mdx` file and then in my `component.stories.ts` be able to provide that parameter.

How do I go about doing this? The documentation isn't very clear to me about whether this is possible and if it is possible how to go about it.